# In Entity Framework, how do I deal with multiple foreign keys of the same class

Tags: .net, entity-framework-5

So I have Two classes Defined as such

```
public class Group
{
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users{ get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that there are two relations between the group and users.  One is that Any group can only have one User that is the Creator.  The other is that a group has many users as members.

I was wondering how I can define this using the convention based definition, or would I need to use another method since it could not infer it from just naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is add another virtual property of type `User` to the `Group` entity:

```
public class Group
{
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }


    public virtual User Creator { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Groups).WithMany(g => g.Users)
    .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("UserId")
        .MapRightKey("GroupId")
        .ToTable("UserGroup"));
```

***SQL Tables Output***

[image: SQL Tables]

Comment: Is that fluent mapping required?

Comment: @indigo0086 yes, otherwise EF will not create that `UserGroup` table for the many to many relationship